# Different Linear Formula in Same Chart in Excel

Tags: excel, graph

I want to ask something. I have data close to the lineare in Excel but with different values:

```
Y:
88.0
87.4
86.5
83.2
X:
2004
3002
3900
4500
```

I have created a graph from these values, as a linear, I would like to show the equation of each duo separately on the same graph in excel.

For example: How can I do this, provided that the equation of the curve formed between 88.0-87.4 and 2004-3002 is separate, the equation of the other sequential duo is separate but the same graphite? We can show a single formula, but how can I do it separately?

Like in below photo ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excel 365
The four points can be fitted exactly to a smooth curve.
Extra/Interpolated points shown.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/pbebljzpie6d454/05_13_22a.xlsx/file
https://www.mediafire.com/file/bsbd3mxr0vd4w84/05_13_22a.pdf/file